# my asp.net counter did not work

Tags: asp.net

i have a counter for counting reserved seats . i want when seat count is going over 2 the website give an error to the client . but this counter did not work . the client can reserve over 2 seat and its bad .please help me .

```
    protected void btn_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int t = 0;
    int c = 0;

if(t<=2){

    string seatname;
    string seatnumber;

    seatname = DropDownList1_SeatName.SelectedItem.ToString();
    seatnumber = DropDownList2_SeatNumber.SelectedItem.ToString();

    //چک کردن انتخاب نکردن دو صندلی تکراری توسط یک نفر
    string strquery = "select count(*) from SingleSeatTable where SeatNumber=@SeatNumber";

    SqlConnection connection2 = DBConnection.getConnection();
    connection2.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd2.Connection = connection2;
    cmd2.CommandText = strquery;

    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@SeatNumber", seatnumber);

    int intRowCount1 = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
    connection2.Close();


    if (intRowCount1 == 1)
    {
        Messages myMsg = new Messages(); // ایجاد نمونه از کلاس
        myMsg.CreateMessageAlert("صندلی رزرو شده است . صندلی دیکری انتخاب نماییدو یا در صورت رزرو تمامی صندلی ها میز و شماره صندلی را دیگری انتخاب نمایید.");

    }


    else
    {
        /////////////////////counter
        //   int t = 0;
        //  int c = 0;

        //  if(t<=2){

        string strQuery = "INSERT INTO [SingleSeatTable](SeatNumber,TableName,EventCode,Reserved,customer_id)" + "VALUES(@SeatNumber,@TableName,@EventCode,@Reserved,@customer_id)";

        SqlConnection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;

        string cis = Session["customerID"].ToString();
        /******query No.1********/
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SeatNumber", seatnumber);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableName", seatname);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EventCode", "100");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reserved", "1");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", cis);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        Response.Redirect("ReservationSucces.aspx");
        t = c++;
        // t = c++;
        //  }
    }



    }

          else
        {
            Messages myMsg = new Messages(); // ایجاد نمونه از کلاس
            myMsg.CreateMessageAlert("ظرفیت رزرو شما پر شده است . شما نمی توانید بیش از دو صندلی انتخاب نمایید");
        }


       }
```

Comment: any one can help me?

Comment: your logic t = c++;  return t value 0 and set c value to 1. what really you want ?

Comment: i want when the client reserve a seat ,the t set to 1,when the client reserev  again the t set to 2 . i want when t set to 2 and client want reserv seat again website give an error to the client ex(you can not reserv over 2 seat). maximum seat reserv number is 2.

Comment: i have posted answer, try this one may it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter is not working because t and c variable scope lies inside click function. Every time you call this function it's reset the t and c value to 0(zero).

> Before inserting into table first check the seats count for every customer from the db.

```
     Messages myMsg = new Messages();
    short seatCounts = 0;
            string sql=  "select count(customer_id) from SingleSeatTable where customer_id =@customer_id";
            SqlConnection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@customer_id"].Value = cis;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                seatCounts = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

              myMsg.CreateMessageAlert(ex.Message);            
            }
    if(seatCounts < 2)
    {
     //allow to insert another seat
    }
    else 
    {
      myMsg.CreateMessageAlert("you can not add more than two seats"); //or your message
   }
```

Comment: Would you say that before executing query i should check seat numbers?

Comment: you mentioned that customer can only reserve 2 seats. so every time first check, how many seats reserved by that customer.

Comment: ok thank you, but in what function should i check ?should i create a function?

Comment: Paste your insert logic inside the if condition.

Comment: if your problem achieved then please accept the answer

Comment: Thank you dear, my problem was solved,im not use your code but your code & your logic was very helpfull to me . thank you again .

Comment: @haik_khosrovian 
it's ok.. keep it up